# Como aplicar internacionalização em um app Android?

Tags: android

Como aplicar internacionalização em um app Android? Na página de publicação do app no play store, existe uma aba sobre traduções, só ela o suficiente? Como aplicar? Ou existe outra forma? Estou em dúvida pois sou iniciante na área.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não, não é apenas dessa forma que se faz **i18n** em um aplicativo Android. Essa forma é apenas em relação a lingua em que seu app é mostrado na *Google Play*, não afeta como os textos do seu app irá variar para cada linguagem.

Você pode internacionalizar os elementos que descrevem seu app no *Google Play*, e eles são:

1. Textos que aparecem no **Store Listing** (Listagem de loja), isso é, o título do app, a descrição completa e a descrição curta.
2. Os **Graphic Assets** são: Screenshots (Telefone ou Tablet's de 7 e 10 polegadas), o Ícone em alta resolução e o **Feature Graphic**. Você pode mostrar imagens diferenciadas para cada língua.
3. Descrição da atualização do seu app (que é mostrada sempre que você atualiza o apk).

Nessas três categorias você define elementos (textos, imagens, vídeos) em cada uma das linguagens que você definir que seu app poderá ser exibido no *Google Play*.

Esse seria um exemplo de como é definido as linguagens em que os elementos que descrevem seu app será apresentado na **Google Play**:

[image: Apresentação das linguagens do Google Play]

## Introdução rápida aos *resources*

Como deve saber, todo aplicativo Android possui **recursos** (*s*).

Os recursos de um aplicativo Android são arquivos, que ficam hierarquicamente a partir do caminho `/res/`. E podem ser de vários tipos:

1. Arquivos de layouts em geral (seja de uma `Activity`, um `Fragment` ou item de um `ListView`). Eles ficam na pasta `/res/layout`;
2. Drawables (gráficos em geral) ficam na pasta `/res/drawable`;
3. Animações: Os arquivos de animações ficam na pasta `/res/anim`;
4. Valores em geral ficam na pasta `/res/values`, neles são colocados qualquer recurso que possa ser usado na aplicação (`Strings`, `Integers`, `Dimensions`, `Styles`, `Colors`, `Attributes`).

Existem muitos outros, não vou me extender muito para não desviar do assunto principal. Para mais detalhes dê uma olhada na documentação sobre [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).

E esses recursos podem ser "qualificados" para determinadas propriedades do dispositivo onde irá rodar, eles não são obrigatórios. As propriedades mais comuns são:

1. Densidade de tela: `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` e entre outras.
2. Orientação: `land` (para landscape), `port` (para portrait).
3. Tamanho de tela: `sw600dp`, `w600dp`, `sw720dp`, `w720p` e muitas outras.
4. Versões de API: `vN`, onde N é qualquer do Android (1, 2, 3 e etc...)
5. Linguagem: Como o próprio nome diz, ele qualifica um determinado recurso para uma determinada linguagem.
6. Região: Análogo que a linguagem, mas para um determinado país.

Um exemplo seria: `/res/drawable-ldpi`, `/res/drawable-mdpi`, `/res/values-pt`.

Existe a precedência dos qualificadores, onde o **locale** tem a maior precedência entre os demais.

Esse aqui é um exemplo da organização de recursos e códigos de um app Android, é claro que pode variar dependendo de vários fatores:

[image: exemplo da organização de recursos e códigos de um app Android]

## Internacionalização

Para começar a internacionalizar, o correto é nunca ter `Strings` **Hardcoded**, nem em Layouts e nem em código, e sim dentro de um *resource* de `String`. Esse é um dos [itens do check-list de localização](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html#manage-strings).

Aliando a recuperação de `String` de *resources* e os qualificadores de linguagem é que é possível internacionalizar um app.

Um **resource** de `String` (por exemplo: `/res/values/strings.xml`) é dessa forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Nome do App</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    // Demais strings
</resources>
```

**OBS**: Vale a pena reforçar que você pode dar o nome que quiser ao arquivo, como por exemplo `/res/values/qualquercoisa.xml`, porém existe a boa prática de dar nomes significativos. O Android não ve nomes de arquivos nas pastas (as pastas é que são importantes) quando vai compilar seus *resources* (é o aapt quem faz o processamento e criação do arquivo binário que é embarcado no apk).

Para recuperar uma dessas `String's` em um código, basta usar o `Context`:

```
String appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
```

O `Context` pode ser uma `Activity`, `Application`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` entre outros...

Para usar uma dessas `String's` em outro *resource*, basta usar uma referência:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name" /> <!-- Aqui você referencia a String da chave app_name.
```

Quando usa-se qualificadores de linguagem em um resource de `values` para Português e Francês seria:

```
- /res
    - /values
        - strings.xml
        - outros...
    - /values-pt
        - strings.xml
        - outros...
    - /values-fr
        - strings.xml
        - outros...
    - Demais resources
```

Nesse caso, quando seu app rodar em um dispositivo que seja de uma dessas línguas (Português ou Francês), ele irá recuperar o *resource* de `String` (`strings.xml`) que melhor se qualifica para a linguagem do dispositivo (`/res/values-pt/strings.xml` ou `/res/values-fr/strings.xml`). Sendo assim, recuperará a `String` na língua correta.

Quando não houver nenhum *resource* que se qualifique (alguém dos Estados Unidos por exemplo) para uma determinada chave, ele irá escolher o padrão (`/values/strings.xml`). Caso também não haja, ele irá gerar uma `RuntimeException` durante a execução.

Para mais informações, dê uma olhada em [Localizing with Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Além disso, o *Google Play* tem um [serviço de tradução profissional](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html#gp-trans), onde ele recebe seus *resources* de `String` e lhe devolve na língua que deseja, mas é pago.

Comment: Valeu @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira, passou despercebido, mais de uma vez :/ Agradeço o toque.

Comment: `@wakim` agora está tudo certo! se puder votar nas minhas perguntas e respostas eu agradeço desde já!

Comment: Resposta espetacular.

Answer (score 0):

Bem, para fazer a tradução dos aplicativos, você deverá trabalhar com os arquivos de strings do seu app. Para cada linguagem desejada pode ser criado um arquivo que contenha o texto traduzido. Desta forma você poderá trabalhar com a localização em que seu app está sendo executado e utilizar o dicionário de palavras/frases mais adequado para a região. [Aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) você pode conferir algumas recomendações e formas de se trabalhar com esta funcionalidade.

Quanto ao serviço de tradução que é oferecido na Google Play, você terá que enviar seu arquivo de textos e selecionar os idiomas que você quer traduzir, no entanto você terá que pagar por este serviço.