# Como modificar elementos de XML com Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

Nunca trabalhei com XML antes. Criei o seguinte XML `configs.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="ip"></string>
    <string name="username"></string>
    <string name="password"></string>
    <string name="banco"></string>
    <string name="porta"></string>
    <string name="funcionario"></string>
    <string name="ultimoUpdate"></string>
</resources>
```

Como acessar e modificar os campos acima com linguagem Java?

Comment: Se você procura um tutorial veja este [aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html)

Comment: Você esta trabalhando com que plataforma?
android?

Comment: estou com android

Comment: Lucas, esta colocando esse arquivo na pasta `res/values`? Se for, você pode acessar através da classe `Resources` usando o identificador. Não precisa fazer parse de xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A resposta aborda dois assuntos:

1. Resources;
2. SharedPreferences.

---

## Resources

Para usar `String's` na plataforma Android não é necessário fazer *parsing* de XML.

O Android possui uma API de recursos ([`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)) muito rica.

Os recursos ficam organizados a partir da pasta `/res/values` do seu projeto. E são tratados de forma hierarquica, isso é, existem alguns **modificadores** que podem fazer com que alguns recursos sobreescrevam outros. Por exemplo, já deve ter visto que existem pastas com sufixos `xhdpi`, `mdpi`, `large`, `sw600dp` e entre outros.

Além disso, essa característica de "hierarquia" (não sei bem o termo correto) é bastante usada para internacionalizar aplicativos, isso pode ser visto com mais detalhes nessa pergunta: [Como aplicar internacionalização em um app Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33360/como-aplicar-internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-app-android)

Exemplos de recursos seriam: Animações, Cores, `Drawables`, Layouts, `String's` e muito mais. A lista completa você pode verificar na documentação oficial em: [Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).

Em relação as `String's`, é recomendado que coloque seu **XML**, nesse mesmo formato, na pasta `/res/values`, por questões de organização e padronização. Para mais detalhes, recomendo a leitura dessa documentação: [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Quando seu aplicativo é compilado, o **aapt** compila todos os seus recursos e gera a classe [`R`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html), onde possui identificadores para todos os seus recursos.

A partir dos identificadores é possível acessar os recursos em tempo de execução, tudo através da classe `Resources`.

No caso das `String's`, você acessa através do caminho: `R.string.id_da_sua_string`.

Para acessar o `Resources`, pode depender um pouco de onde está seu código.

Numa `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Service` ou qualquer classe que extenda da classe `Context` (tirando o `Fragment`), basta usar `getResources()`, para `String's` a própria classe `Activity` fornece o `getString(int resId)`, mas é apenas um atalho para o `getResources().getString(int resId)`.

Em qualquer outro lugar, ou você terá uma referência para um `Context` ou caso contrário poderá usar um Singleton da classe `Application`. Usando a segunda alternativa, é muito comum fazer:

```
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {

    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Declarando no `AndroidManifest`:

```
<application
    android:name="seu.pacote.MyApplication"
    ...
/>
```

Usando essa alternativa:

```
String s = MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.suaString);
```

Se o acesso é dentro de um arquivo de `Layout` ou qualquer outro recurso (inclusive os recursos de `String's`), basta referenciar dessa forma: `@string/sua_string`.

---

## SharedPreferences

Os recursos gerenciados pela API de `Resources` são de apenas leitura. Para poder gerenciar as informações que precisa, terá que usar alguma espécie de armazenamento persistente.

Nesse contexto, recomendo o uso de `SharedPreferences`, onde a característica principal é guardar preferências do tipo chave-valor de usuário, privados ao seu aplicativo. O `SharedPreferences` aceita diversos tipos primitivos, o que acredito que no seu caso é suficiente.

Para recuperar um `SharedPreferences`, basta ter acesso a um `Context`:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.chave_da_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o nome, sempre use o mesmo nome para recuperar os mesmos valores.

Um modo mais simples é:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Lembrando que o `getPreferences` usa o `name` como `getLocalClassName()`.

O acesso aos dados é feito usando o próprio `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String ipPadrao = getResources().getInteger(R.string.ip);
String ipUsuario = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.chave_ip), ipPadrao);
```

Nesse código, recupero o ip que guardar nos `Resources` porque pode ser que não tenha ainda colocado esse valor no `SharedPreferences`. o `getString` precisa de uma chave e recebe um segundo parâmetro informando o valor que será retornado caso não tenha essa chave ainda.

Para escrever, você precisa usar o `SharedPreferences.Editor`, que iniciará uma "transação" e ao final da escrita precisa dar *commit* nas alterações no `SharedPreferences`.

A escrita seria:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

editor.putString(getString(R.string.chave_ip), ip);
editor.commit();
```

Você pode ter múltiplas instâncias do `SharedPreferences`, quando você da *commit* numa edição em alguma delas, todas as instâncias são sincronizadas, e através do `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` você pode ser notificado de alguma mudança, caso queira.

Mais detalhes em [Saving Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

A titulo de curiosidade, o `SharedPreferences` também é serializado no disco como **XML**, e poderá ver nos dados do seu aplicativo em `/data/data/NOME_DO_PACOTE/shared_prefs/NOME_DO_SHARED_PREFERENCES.xml`.

Comment: Boa resposta wakim! mas não deveriamos esperar ele se pronunciar?

Comment: @Joannis Se tem a tag Android, podemos assumir com segurança que está a utilizar Android e as respostas referentes a Android estão corretas.

Comment: @Zuul, agora eu entendi o que o @Joannis quis dizer... Minha resposta não atende... Ele quer modificar, li rápido e não percebi. Acho que a resposta que ele quer é usar `SharedPreference`.

Comment: Pois, estava a ler melhor também e parece que sim... @Joannis, mais atento que todos nós :)

Comment: Vou esperar o OP responder, se for o caso eu excluo a resposta.

Comment: Boa resposta mas e para setar? estou guardando valores  que podem ser alterados de dentro da aplicação

Comment: @LucasBertollo, atualizei minha resposta com uma outra solução.